# Is charge pump with DC/DC LDO suitable for low-noise amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, noise, ldo

I use LTC6268-10 as a pre-amplifier with the gain of 500. I would like to implement the positive and negative power supply. Could someone give me the idea whether the charge pump DC/DC with LDO is good option for the power supply of pre-amplifier or not. The device(s) is something like, LTC1928-5 or TI LM27762 (dual-output for ±VDD)

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: LTC6268 is a 5V opamp, so you can't use +5/-5 supplies (that would be 10V)

Comment: We can't answer that because we don't know what your system specs are.  Take a look at the ripple on the charge pump, the PSRR of the LDO at the ripple frequency and harmonics, and the PSRR of the op amp to get a rough idea of how much impact the charge pump would have on the output.  Then if it looks OK simulate it to be sure or build and test it.  No way for us to know if it's a good option for your system or not.  (Plus what @bobflux`said.)

Comment: I used LTspice to simulate this devise under ±2.1V. The current consumption of LTC6268-10 is about 20mA. I plan to use TI LM27762 ( set dual-output at ±2.1V). Unfortunely, I didn't find the simulation model can be fit into LTspice.  LTC1928-5 is only for evaluating the magnitue of ripple. If 10V is applied to LTC6268-10, then the surface temperture is too high.